# Flatten array to 1 line

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce, flat

Hey I need some help here in javascript

```
[ [ 0, 0, 0, -8.5, 28, 8.5 ],
  [ 1, 1, -3, 0, 3, 12 ],
  [ 2, 2, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 5.333333333333333 ] ]
```

I want that array above to be in the form of this

```
 0 0 0 -8.5 28 8.5, 1 1 -3 0 3 12, 2 2 -0.5 0 0.5 5.333333333333333
```

concat and reduce is placing a comma after each value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arr.map(item => item.join(' ')).join(',');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it simply using [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) & [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

***Example:***

```js
var myArr = [ [ 0, 0, 0, -8.5, 28, 8.5 ],
  [ 1, 1, -3, 0, 3, 12 ],
  [ 2, 2, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 5.333333333333333 ] ];
  
  var str = myArr.map(insideArr => insideArr.join(" ")).join();
  
  console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

This question can be answered in 2 steps. First, flatten out the array using the Array.prototype.reduce() higher order function with the spread operator (...). Then, use the Array.prototype.join() method to convert the flattened array into a list of numbers.

```
const arr = [ [ 0, 0, 0, -8.5, 28, 8.5 ],
  [ 1, 1, -3, 0, 3, 12 ],
  [ 2, 2, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 5.333333333333333 ] ];

const flatten = arr.reduce((combine, item) => [...combine, ...item], [])
                   .join(' ');
```